# Reverse table rows with JQuery without touching the header rows

Tags: jquery, html, dom, dom-manipulation

I have the following HTML table structure. I need to reverse the order of the table rows following every header row. The header rows must stay intact.

```html
<tbody>
  <tr><td colspan="4">Header</td></tr>
  <tr class="content">content 4</tr>
  <tr class="content">content 3</tr>
  <tr class="content">content 2</tr>
  <tr class="content">content 1</tr>
  <tr><td colspan="4">Header 2</td></tr>
  <tr class="content">content 2</tr>
  <tr class="content">content 1</tr>
  <tr><td colspan="4">Header 3</td></tr>
  <tr class="content">content 2</tr>
  <tr class="content">content 1</tr>
</tbody>
```

I have tried the following code to reverse the rows:

```
$("tbody").each(function(elem,index) {
 var arr = $.makeArray($(".content",this).detach());
 arr.reverse();
 $(this).append(arr);
```

});

Yet it messed up my header rows.

I have originally tried inserting the rows using

```html
JQuery.after()
```

But it inserted the rows in the opposite order than I wanted it to. Any ideas what else could be done here?

Comment: are you sure of the validity of your html for the table?

Comment: I would first correct the html code, then start from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your HTML is invalid. The `.content` `tr` elements should have `td` wrapping the content. Secondly, if you add a class to the heading `tr` elements, you can then loop over them and use `nextUntil()` to find the `tr` elements between. Finally, you can reverse the order of the `tr` under the heading by looping over them, and appending them directly after the current header `tr`. Try this:

```js
$('tr.header').each(function() {
  var $header = $(this);
  $(this).nextUntil('.header').each(function() {
    $(this).insertAfter($header);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="4">Header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>content 4
        <td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>content 3
        <td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>content 2
        <td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>content 1
        <td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="4">Header 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>content 2
        <td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>content 1
        <td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="4">Header 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>content 2
        <td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>content 1
        <td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As I mentioned above, this only reverses the order of the elements. If you specifically need to order them, you can change the second loop to your own implementation of `sort()`, as required.